# Dynamic height of label inside UITableCell on rotation

Tags: ios, uitableview

What I want is a tableview of posts presented as cards. (like in Facebook app for example)

I've made a dynamic uitableview with custom uitablecell and located there a uiview with 2 labels - title and subtitle. Cell height is measured manually according to predicted labels height inside heightForRowAtIndexPath and labels height is measured automatically by low priority height constraints.

Everything works great in portrait mode. Once orientation changes to landscape - uitablecell and uiview inside it changes their height perfectly, but labels height controlled by constraints remains the same as it were before rotation.

[Some screenshots](http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130720/MPf09F1d.jpg)

UPDATE:

[Just made a bottom space constraint...](http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130720/jMKJ073w.png) I cant actually believe it because i've been doing this before with no help but everything looks close to normal. A little labels height lag is still here..

CODE:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSInteger title_size = 17;
    NSInteger subtitle_size = 14;

    NSInteger card_horizontal_margin = 10 * 2;
    NSInteger cell_horizontal_margin = 10 * 2;
    NSInteger full_horizontal_margin = card_horizontal_margin + cell_horizontal_margin;

    NSInteger nameHeight = 0;
    NSInteger descHeight = 0;

    NSArray *items = [userDefaults objectForKey: feedType];
    NSString *descText = [[items valueForKey:@"description"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *nameText = [[items valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSInteger line_width = self.tableView.frame.size.width - full_horizontal_margin;

    if (![nameText isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {

        CGSize nameTextSize = [nameText sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:title_size] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(line_width, 1000.0f) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        nameHeight = nameTextSize.height;
    }

    if (![descText isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {

        CGSize descTextSize = [descText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:subtitle_size] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(line_width, 1000.0f) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        descHeight = descTextSize.height;
    }

    NSInteger full_height = nameHeight + descHeight + 50;

    return full_height;

}
```

**HOW DID I FIX THIS**

Just made 2 high priority constraints for each label and measured them in layoutSubviews method of the cell class. That was super easy and everything now works great.

Comment: Have you tried adding a constraint from the bottom of subtitle to the bottom of the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the label height to change along with the cell height, just make sure you have height constraints to the top and bottom of the cell, and no fixed height constraint. If your two labels are on top of each other, the top one should have a constraint to the top of the cell, and one from its bottom to the top of the bottom label. The bottom label should then have one to the bottom of the cell.

Comment: Everything is made just like you said except of two things:
1. spacing constraints are connected to uiview inside the cell.
2. i dont have a spacing constraints to the bottom of that uiview beacause i've been trying to do so and there were problems even in the original orientation.

everything is shown in the picture

Comment: Try adding a constraint from the bottom of the subtitle label to the bottom of the UIView, and then delete the height constraints that you have on the labels.

Comment: http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20130720/nH715h3C.png

portrait is still ok but landscape looks totally broken.

Comment: @DenisSmirnov, I can't tell what's going wrong without seeing the code where you calculate the heights and return a new height for the cell. Please post that code in your question.

Comment: @DenisSmirnov, it looks like the problem is that the constraint system doesn't know how to divide up the space between the two labels -- one has too little and the other has too much. I'm not sure how to fix this -- you might have to give one of the labels a fixed height and modify that in code after you calculate its size. You can make an IBOutlet to the height constraint in IB, then change its constant value in code, like: self.heightCon.constant = nameHeight; where heightCon is the IBOutlet to the height constraint.

Comment: But where should I do that ? Cell is only created after heightForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Just made 2 high priority constraints for each label and measured them in layoutSubviews method of the cell class. That was super easy and everything now works great.